# Can I make IntelliJ's Java formatter separate blocks of fields with the same visibility by a blank line?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ's formatter to format my Java code. My settings include IntelliJ's defaults to rearrange fields depending on their visibility. For example, this will place `public` before `protected` before `private` class members:

Before:

```java
protected int g;
private int x;
public int a;
```

After:

```java
public int a;
protected int g;
private int x;
```

Is there a possibility to make IntelliJ add a blank line in between blocks of fields with the same visibility? I.e.

Intended after:

```java
public int a;

protected int g;

private int x;
```

I found the option to insert "section rules" that allow me to specify comments to enter before and after sections. However, that settings won't let me enter something non-commenty, i.e. if I leave the field blank it will turn it into `//`, and if I enter something like `\n`, it will turn it into `//\n`. So this does not serve blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, feel free to [vote for the corresponding feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125024).